# Caching data in a shared class

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching

Can someone please tell me why this wont work?  If I put the test function into the code behind it works fine.  If I put it into the test class the data is always nothing.

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ASPxGridView1.DataSource = TestClass.Test()
    ASPxGridView1.DataBind()
    ASPxLabel1.Text = Now
End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestClass
Public Shared Function Test() As DataTable
    Test = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Cache("Test"), DataTable)
    If Test Is Nothing Then
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM test "
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(Materials.Conn)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                Dim dep As New SqlCacheDependency(cmd)
                Test = New DataTable
                conn.Open()
                Test.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Test", Test, dep, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromHours(24))
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: did you try passing null instead of that "dep"?

Comment: Does HttpContext object exist in any meaningful sense in the test class, that is one of those ugly framework objects that exist in ASP.NET WebForms that are very difficult to test.

Comment: That works but I would like to have the dependency. I guess then my question is why wont the cache dependency work in the shared function.

Comment: ben f. - I dont understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You must return some DataTable value back !

**Update**: I added `SqlDependency.Start(connstring)` with the absence of this line you should have seen error. That indicates Test Is Not Nothing

```
Public Class TestClass
Public Shared Function Test() As DataTable
    Test = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Cache("Test"), DataTable)
    If Test Is Nothing Then
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * from categories"
        Dim constring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HalloweenConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                Dim dep As New SqlCacheDependency(cmd)
                SqlDependency.Start(constring)
                Test = New DataTable
                conn.Open()
                Test.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Test", Test, dep, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromHours(24))
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Returning the data is not the problem.  And you dont have to return if treat the function itself as a table. ie Test.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))

Comment: I am doing it in the global.asax.

Comment: It works in either case, so are you receiving an error or no data. If no data check if the table has data

Comment: **If I put the test function into the code behind it works fine. If I put it into the test class the data is always nothing.**

Comment: I understood, I tried it also, and it works fine with me. I think I've encountered this problem before where Data Access layer Classes didn't return any data (I was not using caching) . I searched lot. asp.net Forum users are complaining about this.  problem. [See their different suggestions](http://forums.asp.net/t/962050.aspx/3/10). I'll let you know if I find a solution. +1 for the real challenge

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it.  I am still not clear on why I have to pass the sqlcachedepency.

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dep As SqlCacheDependency = Nothing
    ASPxGridView1.DataSource = TestClass.Test(dep)
    ASPxGridView1.DataBind()
    ASPxLabel1.Text = Now
End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestClass
Public Shared Function Test(ByRef dep As SqlCacheDependency) As DataTable
    Test = DirectCast(HttpRuntime.Cache("Test"), DataTable)
    If Test Is Nothing Then
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM test "
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(Materials.Conn)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                dep = New SqlCacheDependency(cmd)
                Test = New DataTable
                conn.Open()
                Test.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Test", Test, dep, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromHours(24))
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Function
End Class
```